# math operations with hours,minutes and seconds

Tags: lua

I work with decimal times in Lua and make arithmetical operations on them.
For example 124500+5=124505 (12:45:05)
What formula can avoid 60 digits problem?
124459+5=124504 (not 124464)
How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing formation with calculation. The best way is to transform your time "string" in a real number:

```
12:45:05 -> 12 * 60 * 60 + 45 * 60 + 05 = 45905
```

The function could look like this:

```
function time_to_number(t)
    return (math.floor(t / 10000) * 60 * 60) + ((math.floor(t / 100) % 100) * 60) + (t % 100)
    -- you can also use % 10000 if the hours are limited to two digits
end
```

Now you can calculate on the seconds.

To format the value back you can use this function

```
function time_split(t)
    local hour = math.floor(t / 3600)
    local min = math.floor((t % 3600) / 60)
    local sec = (t % 3600) % 60
    return hour, min, sec  
end
```

I have used many brackets for readability, which are not all required.